# Fusionar sublistas de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Tengo que armar una función donde a partir de una lista ejemplo `k=[[1,2],[3,4]]` me retorne la lista nueva `k =[1,2,3,4]`  utilizando un `for` para el recorrido y `append` para agregarlo a la lista

Comment: Hola Ezequiel, bienvenido a [es.so], te recomiendo pasarte por [tour] y [ask] para conocer por encima el funcionamiento del sitio y cómo realizar buenas preguntas. Las tareas académicas han de venir acompañadas por la investigación previa o código intentado y preguntar por una duda o problema concreto ¿Has intentado algo para resolverlo? Si es así agregalo y explica el problema concreto que tienes, en caso contrario intentalo primero. Solo necesitas dos `for in` anidados  para recorrer las sublistas y usar `append`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

también podría ser así:

```
 k=[[1,2],[3,4]]
 n=[]
 for i in range (len(k)):
     n.extend(k[i])
 print(n)
```

Obviamente no usas ***append***, pero con un sólo ***for*** y la función ***extend*** llenas la nueva lista con cuantas sublistas tuviera la lista anterior, en un único recorrido

Comment: muchisima gracias !!!! me funciona perfecto +1

Answer (score 0):

podría ser algo así:

```
k = [[1,2],[3,4]]
nueva = []
for n, n2 in k[0], k[1]:
    nueva.append(n)
    nueva.append(n2)
print (nueva)
```

Creas una lista vacia y con un `for` que recorra ambas sublistas mediante slicing le agregas a la lista vacia los elementos de las mismas

Comment: muchisima gracias !!!! me funciona perfecto +1

Answer (score 0):

Debe ser especificamente con un solo for?Te dejo la funcion que recorre la lista de listas "k" y luego recorre cada una de las listas internas, toma cada uno de sus elemento y lo va agregando a la lista nueva a retornar

```
def UnirLista(L_listas):
    Lista_nueva = []
    for lista in L_listas:
        for elemento in lista:
            Lista_nueva.append(elemento)
    return Lista_nueva
```

Llamandola en el main

```
################
k = [[1,2],[3,4]]
L = UnirLista(k)
print(L)
```

Comment: muchisima gracias !!!! me funciona perfecto +1